# app_dev.php runs the page, but app.php sends 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I just started working with Symfony2. I created a simple controller in `AppBundle` called `PageController.php` and it has an action called `homeAction(Request $request)`. It all works well and all. Afterwards I ran a command

```
$ php app/console assets:install
```

and ran the server and everything was alright. If I ran `localhost:8000/page/home` (as I set it up in the `@Route`), the page would show up as I expect it to.

Now if I run `localhost:8000/app.php/page/home` I get a

> 404 page not found

error, while if I run it with `localhost:8000/app_dev.php/page/home,` again I get what I want.

I tried 2 things to fix this (both of which I found here, on StackOverflow), neither worked:

1. I tried to run another command

   ```
   $ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
   ```
2. I tried going into `.htaccess` folder and change all of the app.php parts to app_dev.php. It didn't work, so I reverted back to app.php

Comment: Have you tried clearing the prod cache? Usually this helps.

Comment: @thormeier Yep, it did the trick. I'll reserve the answer for you if you want, post it bellow and I'll give you a vote + check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing in development (i.e. `app_dev.php`) changes in annotations trigger the internal cache to be updated, thus no need for an action.

When, in turn, testing it in production environment (i.e. `app.php`) you might want to clear the production cache first, so the annotations cache (as well as doctrine, compiled twig templates etc.) gets updated.

You achieve this by executing `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`, or short `php app/console c:c -e prod`.